# Using Two LEFT JOIN or use AND with single LEFT JOIN?

Tags: sql-server-2012, join

Using two `LEFT JOIN`s i.e.

```
SELECT <some columns>
FROM Table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON <condition1>
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t3 ON <condition2>
```

is this same as using `AND` in single `LEFT JOIN`? i.e.

```
SELECT <some columns>
FROM Table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON <condition1>
AND <condition2>
```

Both are same or different(in general)?

Comment: It depends on your requirement and ON condition. If you put t1.col1=t2.col1 with Table2 and t1.col1.t3.col1 It would be same.

Comment: The second query would be closer to the first one in terms of results if it used OR instead of AND, but it would still be a different query *in general*.

Comment: Try using Explain plan to see the difference :)

Comment: @RajeshRanjan no they wouldn't be equivalent, even in that case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are different. In the first option you get 2 times `Table2` into your query. Once as `t2` and once as `t3`. Both have a different content and you must put them somehow back together. To me this is more an *OR* instead of an *AND*. In the second option you get only the `Table2` rows that meet both criteria.

Suppose you have `Table2` with the following content:

```
| Color | Size |
|-------|------|
| Red   |  S   |
| Blue  |  S   |
| Blue  |  XS  |
```

Suppose you want to have the rows that are `Blue` and `S`. In your first option you get all rows (`t2` for example with all `Blue` and `t3` with all `S`) and in your second option you only get row 2.

Comment: Not only that, but since this is about outer-joining the table twice, you will also get a mini-Cartesian product with the first query. I mean, a `Table1` row wants colour blue and size S. So, the first join gives it two `Table2` matches, thus duplicating the `Table1` row, and the second join gives two matches for each of the copies, thus resulting in four rows in total.